# Developed a website using Bootstrap & it is responsive at some point

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have started developing a website using bootstrap and it is responsive but only to some extend.

If i minimize the browser, the contents auto-arrange itself but as i keep on minimizing at some point the h1 & p contents stop being responsive.`

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>NiKuLsAn DeSiGn</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
            }
        .imageAndText {position: relative;} 
        .imageAndText .col {position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 50px; right: 70px;}
        .imageAndText .col2 {position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 200px; left: 150px;}
        .imageAndText .col3 {position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 50px; left: 150px;}

        p{
        font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="imageAndText">
                <img src="banner1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto;">
                <div class="col">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#" style="font-size:20px;">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="font-size:20px;">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="font-size:20px;">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col3">
                <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" />
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
                <h1>Amazing Dude.</h1>
                <h1>Amazing Life.</h1>
                <p>Welcome to the personal site of <b>John Doe</b><br>A professional skier and a musician.</p>
            </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please help as I am not able to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: You are making website in bootstrap and not even using bootstrap classes.. Use bootstrap classes and css then everything will work good. Right now you are using your own custom css .

Comment: Refer bootstrap from w3school.com, It will help you.

Comment: Hi Sahil, I had to make custom css because i wanted text over an image and i am unable to find how to do that on w3school.com, can you help me out ?

Comment: @SahilDhir Can you help out please

Comment: Surely Give me sometime.. I am currently away from my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an example where  I have used minimal custom CSS and everything else is wprking using bootstrap framework.. Have a look and ask your queries.

```css
body {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1920x400') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Workaround for some mobile browsers */
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.featurette-divider {
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar-wrapper CustomNavbar">

  <div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo Goes here</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>
</div>
<hr class="featurette-divider">

<div class="container ">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h1>Amazing Dude.</h1>
    <h1>Amazing Life.</h1>
    <p>Welcome to the personal site of <b>John Doe</b>
      <br>A professional skier and a musician.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, Some what like this, thank you bro for helping me sort this out.